# Programatically determine the data size in bytes of a search operation

Tags: php, database, quickbase

Is it possible to measure data set in terms of bytes?

I was searching for the same as I was required to calculate the bytes of the search I am making on to a QuickBase Table for some debugging process.

Data set could be as simple as a result of the operation

> Select * from employees

which fetches a 1000 something rows of 5 columns each

Is it possible to calculate that in a PHP application?

I have not been very successful while googling this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe your data set?  If it can be stringified, use strlen().  Per the manual, [http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php]("strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.")

Comment: Just have made an edit @bishop.

Answer (score 1):

[strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) returns the number of bytes consumed, so you should be able to use something like:

```
<?php

// example of what you might get back from a SQL SELECT
$data = array (
    array (1, 'foo', 'bar'),
    array (2, 'baz', 'biz'),
);

// tally up the byte count for every scalar in the set
$bytes = 0;
array_walk_recursive($data, function ($item) use (&$bytes) {
    $bytes += strlen((string)$item);
});

echo $bytes . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Any Idea about QuickBase?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean... are you asking for a way to retrieve data from QuickBase?

Comment: I wanted to know If I could calculate it in terms of Bytes

Comment: I read that you have "a 1000 something rows of 5 columns each" and that you wanted to "calculate [bytes] in a PHP application" -- that's what's above.  Give it rows of data, and you get bytes.  What am I missing?